# Swipe event triggers tap event for ipod touch

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, swipe, tap

I am using jquery mobile beta and jquery 1.6.
On ipod touch, a swipe event is also trigerring the tap event.
This issue is not hapenning on android devices.
I am trying to google out the solution, but looks like there are not many with the same problem. Is there something very basic that I am missing??

```
$("div.totapandswipe").bind('tap',function(event, ui){
    alert('event');
});

$("div.totapandswipe").bind('swipe',function(event, ui){
            alert('event');
});
```

Thank you for the help!

Comment: Can you alert the event type:  alert('Event: '+event.type);

Comment: yes.. it alerts the correct event swipe for swipe and tap for tap...and now I see that the correct code gets executed as per the event trigerred, but after i tried couple of times, I see that for a swipe event i would end up getting an alert for a tap. The only other thing which could be interferring is the scrollview plugin (experiments under jquerymobile) which I am using to contain the swipe area..will look more into that plugin (and get back) and see if there is a conflict of jquery mobile swipe and scrollview swipe... Thanks so much for your time !!

Comment: After running some tests it looks like you're correct: http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/hJtAQ/9/ maybe you can use preventDefault() and trigger the single event. This might be a bug as well

Comment: Updated tests: http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/hJtAQ/11/

Comment: Thanks for your tests Phill!!.,. really appreciate it!..Will event.preventDefault or stopPropgation really work in this?
because both the events are different so for a tap event (after swipe has been executed), until and unless I keep track of that first (swipe) event has already been executed (by using a counter or holding the first event in a variable outside the function), I am not finding a good way to execute the first event only and stp the est... tried return false too.

Comment: I'd love a fix for this as well.

Answer (score 2):

I have found that I needed to unbind('click') as the first option in my bind('swipeleft swiperight') function. Since my swipe goes to a new page, that page re-binds the 'click' event for the page that it just left. My utility is a flashcard that tap brings a new card and swiping flips it over. Good luck.

```
$('#flashVerse').bind('swipeleft swiperight', function(event) {
    console.log(event.type);
    $('#flashVerse').unbind('click');
    if(event.type == 'swipeleft') {
        $.mobile.changePage('flashReference','flip');
    } else {
        $.mobile.changePage('flashReference','flip',true,false);
        console.log('SWIPERIGHT');
    }
});

$('#flashReference').live('pageshow',function(event,ui){
    if((tipsOn() || ls.getItem('tipFlash') == '1') && ui.prevPage.attr('id')!='flashVerse') {
        ls.setItem('tipFlash','0');
        var msg = 'Swipe to flip the card.\n Tap for a new card.\nuse Options to turn Tips back on.';
        if(phoneGap) navigator.notification.alert(msg,dummy,'Flash Cards','OK');
        else alert(msg);
    }
    $('#lnkFlashVerse').addClass('ui-btn-active').addClass('ui-state-persist');
    $('#lnkFlashReference').removeClass('ui-btn-active').removeClass('ui-state-persist');
    $('#flashReference').bind('click', function(event) {
        console.log(event.type);
        newFlashCard();
        //$('#flashReference div[data-role="content"]').append('clicked ');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

This seemed to help me:

```
$("selector").swiperight(function (e) {
  if (e.type === "swiperight") {
    myHandler(e);
  }
});
```

It's lame that this would be an issue.  Jqm bug on this yet?