# certain touch events cause multiple events, how can I limit to the desired event?

Tags: jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-mobile, touch-event

So if I tap or taphold it works as expected, but if I swipe I should get two events. The swipe and the swipedirection, but I also get a tap event as well. is there a way to remove the tap event if swipe or swipedirection occurs?

Live Example:

- http://jsfiddle.net/phillpafford/hJtAQ/11/

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="home"> 
    <div data-role="content">
        <div id="display-event" class="add-border">
            <p>Tap, TapHold (for 1 second), Swipe, SwipeRight or SwipeLeft</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function bindEvent(element) {
    element.bind('tap taphold swipe swiperight swipeleft', function(event, ui) {
       alert('Event: '+event.type); 
    });
}

bindEvent($('#display-event'));
```

Related Question: [Swipe event triggers tap event for ipod touch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6550488/swipe-event-triggers-tap-event-for-ipod-touch)

Update:
 - http://jsfiddle.net/hJtAQ/31/ (using Jaspers method)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to only validate the first event that fires you can set a timeout and `preventDefault()` for the rest of the events fired:

```
function bindEvent(element) {
    element.bind('tap taphold swipe swiperight swipeleft', function(event, ui) {
       if (event_ok == false) {
           event.preventDefault();
           return false;
       } else {
           event_ok = false;
           setTimeout(function () {
               event_ok = true;
           }, 500);
           alert('Event: '+event.type);
       }
    });
}

var event_ok = true;
bindEvent($('#display-event'));
```

Comment: Hmm, this does kinda work, still loose the swipe direction though +1 for the effort

Comment: You can still capture the event type with the `event.type` property. `if (event.type == 'swipeleft') {/*swipeleft code*/}` etc... However I'm not sure what fires first, `swipe` or `swipeleft`/`swiperight`

Comment: swipe fires first. I guess I can put some logic to capture the swipe event and check if another event follow